# CSS Flex fill available height dynamically (without height or position)

Tags: css, flexbox

How do I make CSS Flex fill the available height dynamically without specifying the `height` or `position` (static) properties?

In the XHTML code below I need the light blue box to fill in the space down to the light red element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Flex Vertical Fill Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
#e1, #e2 {float: left; width: 50%;}
#e1 {background-color: #cff;}
#e2 {background-color: #ffc;}
#e3 {background-color: #fcf; clear: both;}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="e1">
<div><p>Needs to use full available height.</p></div>
</div>

<div id="e2">
<p>Automatically generates height from content.</p>
<p>Automatically generates height from content.</p>
<p>Automatically generates height from content.</p>
<p>Automatically generates height from content.</p>
</div>

<div id="e3"><p>Natural content below</p></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I am testing this in Firefox *first*, then Chrome and IE.

Comment: can you create jsfiddle example

Comment: if it ok to adjust the markup?

Comment: @sdcr Highly subjective, the #e1 actually contains multiple child div elements (of varying automatically generated height) but anything beyond that would be too convoluted to probably apply. I'm trying to keep it simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get it work, I added a container for `e1` and `e2`.

```
<div id="e1-e2">
    <div id="e1">
        <p>Needs to use full available height.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="e2">
        <p>Automatically generates height from content.</p>
        <p>Automatically generates height from content.</p>
        <p>Automatically generates height from content.</p>
        <p>Automatically generates height from content.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="e3">
    <p>Natural content below</p>
</div>
```

---

**Option 1: Using `table` and `table-cell` (recommended).**

```
#e1-e2 {
    display: table;
}
#e1, #e2 {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qnz7mao6/

---

**Option 2: Using `flexbox`.**

```
#e1-e2 {
    display: flex;
}
#e1, #e2 {
    width: 50%;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/86n04amt/

---

**Option 3: If you still prefer `float` layout.**

```
#e1-e2 {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#e1, #e2 {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
#e1 {
    background-color: #cff;
    padding-bottom: 1000px;
    margin-bottom: -1000px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/11k8hds9/

---

Tip: Use `padding` instead `margin` for `<p>` to avoid unwanted gaps.

Comment: Well that *should* work but I don't get to learn how to make flexbox work with vertical stretching from this answer which was the whole point of asking the question. *shrug* +1 for the interesting idea though.

Comment: flexbox is cool, but will not work on slightly older browsers http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox I made a quick demo http://jsfiddle.net/86n04amt/ (you still need the container element)

Comment: I'm dumping IE8 and older, IE9 I keep for testing without `XMLHttpRequest` 2.0 but officially support IE10+ so I'm good on support. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I can give some solution in pure css, but it will be correct to do with js.

this is html part

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="fake-bg"></div>
    <div class="fake-bg"></div>
    <div id="e1"><p>Needs to use full available height.</p></div>
    <div id="e2">
        <p>Automatically generates height from content.</p>
        <p>Automatically generates height from content.</p>
        <p>Automatically generates height from content.</p>
        <p>Automatically generates height from content.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<div id="e3"><p>Natural content below</p></div>
```

and css paert

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
.fake-bg {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.fake-bg:nth-of-type(1) {
    background-color: #cff;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.fake-bg:nth-of-type(2) {
    background-color: #ffc;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}

#e1, #e2 {float: left; width: 50%;}
#e1 {background-color: #cff;}
#e2 {background-color: #ffc;}
#e3 {background-color: #fcf; clear: both;}
```

an jsfiddle example

[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/L50rdyx7/)

Comment: What is the point of flexbox if I add new empty elements? I'm open to intrinsic values such as `fill-available` though (even with `-moz-` prefix) they don't work on height apparently. I'm trying to get *away* from IE6 hacks.